# location of storage for profiles in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-profiles

I am new in asp.net and I am not sure about the profiles that whether they store on the client machine or they have a space on the server side??

any one can help me ??

like the following code , where it is stored.

```
 <profiles>
 <properties>
  <add name="masterpage"/>
 </properties>
</profiles>
```

Comment: what you mean by profiles? user profile?

Comment: yes , the profile tag which we use in web.cofig file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the items that you going to place on the profile of the user **are stored on the server**.

When a user login, then you can retrieve this values for the user and you get that data from your server, from your local database.

If you use a database for your user, then there is a table with all the user profile properties.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx

ps The only data that you can save on the user browser is the cookie - and this is limited.